# Chrome/Firefox extension to change YouTube auto caption from English to another language

Tags: chrome, firefox, youtube

By default YouTube translate videos to English. Is there any Chrome/Firefox extension to auto translate to different language?

[image]

Comment: Would Mandarin, French and Polish do – or what languages would you need? Have you already [checked Addons.Mozilla.Org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=youtube+translate&cat=all)?

Comment: @Izzy sir that's what i mean http://imgur.com/a/ZZM6A

Comment: And what languages would you need at least? Arguing by the screenshots: Arabic? I don't know such an extension – but if someone does know, it might still not be made an answer if it's thought "too specific", while it might match your needs.